# Xcode putting in __autorelease when there's ** in the interface

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In which situations do we need to write the __autoreleasing ownership qualifier under ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862023/in-which-situations-do-we-need-to-write-the-autoreleasing-ownership-qualifier)

making this method in the interface:

```
- (NSArray *)questionsFromJSON:(NSString *)jsonString 
                     withError:(NSError **)error;
```

when tabbing out autocomplete in the implementation it's adding this:

```
- (NSArray *)questionsFromJSON:(NSString *)jsonString withError:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
```

I figured with ARC there never needs to be the use of autorelease but I'm guessing this is different, as it compiles fine with ARC.

Just curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autorelease is used a lot in ARC.  You just don't see the keyword sprinkled around all over the place.

The example you site, is when you send a pointer to an object pointer, like the typical error scenario...

```
NSError *error = nil; if (![foo bar:&error]) {
    // handle error
}
```

Note, that the bar method will be doing something like...

```
- (void)bar:(NSError **errorPtr) {
    // blah...
    if (an_error_happened) {
        NSError *error = [NSError muckityMuck];
        *errorPtr = error;
    }
}
```

Now, the error object has been allocated, and "returned" like an autorelease from a function call.  When you declare s function/method to take "**" you are implicitly stating __autorelease.