# From Swift 3, how to use a type defined as an Obj-C block taking an id * pointer as parameter

Tags: objective-c, pointers, closures, swift3

My *Swift 3.0* project uses an Objective-C library that defines a certain type (`AsyncBlock`) as an Obj-C block:

`typedef BOOL (^AsyncBlock)(id __nullable * __nonnull context);`

In Swift 3.0 terms, that should translate into a non optional pointer to an optional value, so I figured I should be able to assign a variable of type `AsyncBlock` to a closure defined in my swift 3 project as follows (not including bridging header and other details for brevity):

`func closure(_ context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Any?>) -> Bool {
  return true
}
var myClosureVariable: AsyncBlock = closure`

The compiler disagrees: `Cannot assign value of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<Any?>) -> Bool' to type 'AsyncBlock'` - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

An Obj-C `id` normally maps to a Swift 3.0 `Any`, but here we have to use `AnyObject` (not sure why). Also we need to use an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` instead of an `UnsafeMutablePointer` (again, not clear as to the reasons why)

This works:

`func closure(_ context: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) -> Bool {
  return true
}
var myClosureVariable: AsyncBlock = closure`

Comment: Objective-C's ARC has to be compatible with manual reference counting. Passing an indirect pointer it is not clear, how that behaves inside the called block, function, method or whatever. There is a convention, that it is passed autoreleased. i. e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862023/in-which-situations-do-we-need-to-write-the-autoreleasing-ownership-qualifier