# Getting 0.2GB extra available space in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsfilemanager, diskspace

When i try to get the available space in iPad i am getting 0.2 GB extra with below code.

```
- (uint64_t)freeDiskspace {
uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;

__autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];

if (dictionary)
{
    NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
    NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
    totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %d", [error domain], [error code]);
}

return totalFreeSpace;
```

Comment: I faced similar problem. NSFileSystemFreeSize returns more 200MB size. But iOS setting and itunes shows 200 MB less that actual, 200MB space may be kept for some purpose by Apple. For safer side i don't let my app use that extra 200MB which also take care that iOS will not slow down due to full mem usage.

Comment: I too having the same problem,.. Any one tell me the solution?...

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - Free space left on device reported incorrectly (+- 200 Mb difference)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270027/iphone-free-space-left-on-device-reported-incorrectly-200-mb-difference)