# getting the iPhone Application's Disk usage

Tags: iphone, disk, diskspace

I am trying to find my iPhone application's disk usage. So i have tried finding the size of my application's home directory. But it does not give the correct value when i compare with usage shown in iPhone 4S Settings->Usage tab for the same application. I have used the following line s of code. Cane anyone says if i am going wrong anywhere or anyone can help me for finding the same.

NSString *path = NSHomeDirectory();
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error: &error];
NSNumber *appDiskSpaceInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSize];

float appDiskSpace = ([appDiskSpaceInBytes floatValue]/1024.0);

Comment: What is the settings tabe reporting and what are you getting programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/ios-how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device

Answer (score 0):

Use 1000 while dividing not 1024. Then it will be in sync with what Usage shows.