# Wrong file system infos

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the value from NSFileSystemFreeSize differ from the free size reported in the iOS Settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717304/why-does-the-value-from-nsfilesystemfreesize-differ-from-the-free-size-reported)

I have this code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *outputDirectory = @"/Users/myuser/Desktop"

NSDictionary *fileSystemAttributes =
 [fileManager attributesOfFileSystemForPath:outputDirectory error:&error];

if (!error) {

    uint64_t freeSpace = (uint64_t)[fileSystemAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];

    NSLog(@"Free space in bytes: %lld.",freeSpace);
}
```

When I execute the code, it gives me around 45 TB of free space, which is totally wrong!

I have tried with

```
outputDirectory = @"/";
```

but it also fails.

Am I missing something?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `NSFileSystemFreeSize` The key in a file system attribute dictionary
>   whose value indicates the amount of free space on the file system. The
>   corresponding value is an `NSNumber` object

You should assign the object you get from `objectForKey:` to a `NSNumber` variable and then extract whatever primitive value you want to use (`freeSpace`) from that.