# How to access iOS device (iPhone/iPad) memory statistics?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, statistics, device

How do we access device memory statistics programmatically? Suppose I want to know whats the devices total memory capacity is. For example, whether it's 16GB, 32Gb or 64GB, and how much has been utilized?

Comment: Duplicate question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device

Answer (score 0):

you can check this through the method `attributesOfFileSystemForPath:`. store the returned value into dictionary and then by using key `NSFileSystemSize`, you can check total memory size and by key `NSFileSystemFreeSize` you can check available memory