# XE4 getting the total disk size

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

can someone points or helps me in getting the IPHONE / IPAD device total disk size using the Delphi XE4 .

i need just a start point , i tried to use the :

```
Device : UIDevice;
```

but it has no reference .

thank you

Comment: What do you mean under 'has no reference'?

Comment: i mean that Device has no reference to disk properties .

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uses
  iOSapi.Foundation, Macapi.ObjectiveC;

function GetTotalDiskSize(FolderName: string): Int64;
var
  Dict: NSDictionary;
  P: Pointer;
const
  FoundationFwk: string = '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation';
begin
  Result := 0;
  Dict := TNSFileManager.Wrap(TNSFileManager.OCClass.defaultManager).attributesOfFileSystemForPath(NSStr(FolderName), nil);
  if Dict = nil then
    Exit;
  P := Dict.objectForKey((CocoaNSStringConst(FoundationFwk, 'NSFileSystemSize') as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  if Assigned(P) then
    Result := TNSNumber.Wrap(P).unsignedLongLongValue;
end;
```