# 200 MB extra freespace in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

Here i need to know the free space available in iOS device. For that i go through with many answers in stackoverflow and finally use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device),

code snippet i am using,

```
- (uint64_t)freeDiskspaceInphone
{
uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;

__autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];

if (dictionary) {
    NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
    NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
    totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu GB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", (((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %d", [error domain], [error code]);
}

return totalFreeSpace/1024/1024;
}
```

In this i get freespace is 978 MB but when i go to `Settings --> General --> Usage` in my iPad it shows like 778 MB Available (freespace). Why i get 200 MB extra where is the mistake happen?. And the device is a jailbroken whether that was the reason?

Comment: @Desdenova how can i do that?

Comment: Nevermind that, even with the bytes there is 200mb difference.

Comment: I spend enough time in this and don't know how to overcome with this issue. Finally, i use a condition like if freespace is greater than  300MB then do that operation otherwise skip that. Hope god tell me the solution as soon as possible.