# swift force-unwrapping exception not propagated

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I've run into this silly behaviour in swift where force-unwrapping an optional does not propagate.

From the documentation:

> Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.

To reproduce:

```
func foo(bar:String?) throws{
    print(bar!);
}
```

And

```
try foo(nil);
```

This does not seem logical or consistent to me and I can't find any documentation on this subject.

Is this by design?

Comment: I'm not sure that throwing an error with `throw` (which is what causes errors to be propagated from within such a function) is the same thing that happens when you force-unwrap a `nil`. I think I read somewhere that it is implemented as an `assert()`.

Comment: That would explain it, but thats terrible. Maybe there is an argument for it but in a language that supports exceptions it just seems inconsistent.

Comment: @Greg: Nicolas is right. Note that try/catch handles Swift *errors* (values conforming to `ErrorType` which are thrown). That is *completely unrelated* to runtime errors or exceptions. (The documentation does not even mention the word "exception" in connection with throw/try/catch, only "Error handling".)

Comment: I guess it's easy to confuse swift errors with exceptions. Most other programming  languages use similar keywords (`try`/`catch`) to deal with exception handling.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html):

> **Error Handling**
>
> Error handling is the process of responding to and recovering from
>   error conditions in your program. Swift provides first-class support
>   for throwing, catching, propagating, and manipulating recoverable
>   errors at runtime.
>
> ...
>
> **Representing and Throwing Errors**
>
> In Swift, errors are represented by values of types that conform to
>   the `ErrorType` protocol. This empty protocol indicates that a type can
>   be used for error handling.

*(Note: `ErrorType` has been renamed to `Error` in Swift 3)*

So with `try/catch` you handle *Swift errors* (values of types that conform to the `ErrorType` protocol) which are `throw`n.
This is completely unrelated to runtime errors and runtime exceptions
(and also unrelated to `NSException` from the Foundation library).

Note that the Swift documentation on error handling does not even use the
word "exception", with the only exception (!) in (emphasis mine) in:

> NOTE
>
> Error handling in Swift **resembles exception handling** in other
>   languages, with the use of the try, catch and throw keywords. Unlike
>   exception handling in many languages—including Objective-C—error
>   handling in Swift does not involve unwinding the call stack, a process
>   that can be computationally expensive. As such, the performance
>   characteristics of a throw statement are comparable to those of a
>   return statement.

The unwrapping of optionals which are `nil` does not `throw` a
Swift error (which could be propagated) and cannot be handled with
`try`.

You have to use the well-known techniques like
optional binding, optional chaining, checking against `nil` etc.

Comment: I've never tried to use try to catch unwrapping, I only talk about them propagating. But you answer that just fine. 

One usecase that I ran into this is using SwiftyJSON and parsing json. I have an Entity that contains a child Entity that would simply throw (propagate) the non-existent field in the json response. 

I now use optional initializers to achive the same thing, but now there are 3 more lines of code :P

Comment: @Greg: Well, any thrown error must be catched somewhere. But I have changed the wording to match your question better.

Answer (score 5):

this 'self explanatory' example can help you to see the difference between raising an runtime exception and throwing an error E conforming to ErrorType protocol.

```
struct E: ErrorType{}
func foo(bar:String?) throws {
    if let error = bar where error == "error" {
            throw E()
    }
    print(bar, "is valid parameter, but don't try to access bar.characters, it crash your code! (if bar == nil)")
    // here is everything OK 
    let bar = bar!
    // but here it crash!!
    _ = bar.characters
}

do {
    try foo("error")
    // next line is not accessible here ...
    try foo(nil)
} catch {
    print("\"error\" as parameter of foo() throws an ERROR!")
}
do {
    try foo(nil) // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
} catch {

}
```

it prints

```
"error" as parameter of foo() throws an ERROR!
nil is valid parameter, but don't try to access bar.characters, it crash your code! (if bar == nil)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

raising an runtime exception is fatal error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

the force-unwrapping is implemented exactly as the documentation described! But you may be looking for something like this:

```swift
try myOptional.unwrapped() // Throws an error if it is `nil`
```

This trowing `unwrapped` function can be implemented simply like:

```
extension Optional {
    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case unexpectedNil
    }

    func unwrapped() throws -> Wrapped {
        if let self { return self }
        else { throw Error.unexpectedNil }
    }
}
```

So now you can `catch Optional.Error.unexpectedNil`