# How to use try-catch in Swift?

Tags: swift, try-catch

I get how I can create my own errors and trigger them in Swift with the `throws` keyword. What I don't get is how to replicate the regular `try - catch` found in other languages (or the Ruby `rescue`) for unhandled exceptions.

Example (In Swift):

```
func divideStuff(a: Int, by: Int) -> Int {
  return a / by
}

let num = divideStuff(4, by: 0)  //divide by 0 exception
```

Here's how I'd deal with it in C#, for example:

```
int DivideStuff(int a, int b) {
  int result;
  try {
    result = a / b;  
  }
  catch {
    result = 0;
  }
  return result;
}
```

How can I achieve the same with Swift?

Comment: It's `do`.. `catch` in the doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: You *cannot* catch arbitrary runtime exceptions (such as division by zero) with try/catch, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628999/swift-force-unwrapping-exception-not-propagated for a similar question and links to the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift there is no functionality to catch arbitrary runtime errors.
The developer is responsible to handle the errors properly.

For example

```
func divideStuff(a : Int, b : Int) -> Int {
  if b == 0 { return 0 }
  return a / b
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know Swift is incapable of catching arbitrary runtime errors. Somehow, this feels odd.

Comment: This does not really explain a try/catch - this is good, but it's defensive programming.

Answer (score 2):

You can also handle it like this:

```
enum MyErrors: ErrorType {
  case DivisionByZero
}

func divideStuff(a: Int, by: Int) throws -> Int {
  if by == 0 {
    throw MyErrors.DivisionByZero
  }
  return a / by
}

let result: Int

do {
  result = try divideStuff(10, by: 0)
} catch {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You may want to add a catch let error as NSError to the do/catch statement so that the error can be identified in the catch portion