# do - try - catch code doesnt try or catch. just do's

Tags: swift, error-handling, try-catch, option-type

thanks for any help upfront.

url session works perfect with connection, it prints the error as nil. but without it it prints the .localizedDescription just fine and shows me the right error, but then continues to do the do{ try } and crashes with this error in the try line:

> Thread 6: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

now I am not even sure if this has anything to do with the errorhandling. thanks for any help with understanding whats going on or just solving the problem!

```
func getData(completion: (() -> ())?) {

    let urlString = URL(string: "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlString!, completionHandler: { (data, response                                                                                                         , error) in

        print("before entering do-try-catch", error?.localizedDescription)

        do {

            //create Dictionary
            print("downloading content")

            self.coinData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [[String:Any]]

            //set connection status
            self.connection = true

            //update tableView
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?()
            }

        } catch {

            print("catch", error.localizedDescription)

            //set connection status
            self.connection = false

            //update tableView
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?()
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Make sure the data can be converted to json

Comment: try/catch handles *Swift errors,* not arbitrary runtime exceptions, compare [swift force-unwrapping exception not propagated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628999/swift-force-unwrapping-exception-not-propagated).

Answer (score 2):

`Thread 6: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` is a common problem for beginners.

You try to work with data that is not there. 
So for example in your code you force to execute `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)`

When `data` is `nil` the code will crash.

The same at the beginning `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlString!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) {}`

When `urlString` is not a valid URL the code will be crash. (In this case the url seems to be valid).

For more information have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24034551/4420355

Try the following snipped it should work

```
if let data = data {
 self.coinData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:Any]]
     //... work with coinData
 }
```

Comment: Okay thank you lot. in what case though would the try do its job and give over to the catch? isnt the idea of the try that if anything behind it (in that line, i think) fails, it cancels the process and gives over to the catch?

Answer (score 1):

Reason why it is crashing is because `data` is Optional and it should be nil or has some value. On line

```
self.coinData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [[String:Any]]
```

Compiler thinks:

Let's take a look and unwrap this Optianal variable. But it's `nil`, there is "nothing"! So what should I unwrap? Let's crash and throw Fatal Error message.

How to easily avoid this with Optional binding:

```
if let data = data {
....do something with data
} else {
...print error message
}
```

For more information take look at this brilliant answer.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170457/3046686