# how to handle space not available while recording video exception in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer

In my application I have implemented custom video recorder using AVplayer. I wanted to show message to user when space not available in the device while recording video. Can anyone please help me how to deal with this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check available/free disk space on the iPhone/iPad device.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to calculate it real time, when the video recording is going on

Comment: @AkshaykumarMaldhure Did you find a way to detect the storge while recording, and what if I have consumed all the memory then would I able to save the recorded video?

Comment: @Mr.Kushwaha not yet