# How can I find the total disk size of the device my app is running on?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, disk

I want to know what is the total disk size of the device my app is running on. For example, I want to find whether it is an iphone6 16gb or 32gb.

In `SystemInfo`, there is a property `systemMemorySize`. But that returns the amount of RAM. I want to find the hard disk size. How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is it necessary to know this for a game?

Comment: So basically, it is an app not a game. I updated my question. I want to show the user his device's specs. But I don't know native iOS development. So, I decided to use Unity.

Comment: Oh, I saw Unity and thought "game". Nvm

Comment: So any idea about the solution?

Comment: No, sorry, my comment was pure curiosity. I've never done IOS development.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device this may  help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DriveInfo` class is used to do something like on Windows or Desktop computers. Not sure if that will work on iOS since it uses the `GetDrives()` function to get disk size. The real solution is to make a native plugin with Objective-C.

Luckily, there is a *free* plugin for this called [*Simple Disk Utils*](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/59382) on the Asset store. You can also get its source code from [here](https://github.com/dkrprasetya/simple-disk-utils).

Available functions:

```
int CheckAvailableSpace(); 
int CheckBusySpace();
int CheckTotalSpace(); //<--- You need this
```

Comment: I'll check this now and will let you know in a while.

Comment: Since I'm working on an app, and I want to show detailed information to user about his device, I now want to show whether his device is rooted (for android) or jailbroken (for ios). Should I open a new question for that?

Comment: Yes, this is totally a different topic

Comment: Can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347749/www-text-not-showing-complete-data-in-android