# www.text not showing complete data in android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, web

I'm using the following code to get the text from a web page:

```
    private IEnumerator FetchText() {
        WWW www = new WWW(URL);

        yield return www;

        if(www.error == null) {
            myText.text = www.text.Length.ToString();
        }
        ...
    }
```

When I run this in Unity, I get `185616` characters long string. But when I run this in android device, I get only `47133` characters. Is it because that web page behaves differently in Windows and Android? If yes, how can I fetch the same content from android as I'd be getting from desktop PC.

Thanks.

Comment: Its very likely that the problem is the web-site/webservice detecting your User-Agent. They can also use other headers to change the reponse. Does this code work in the Editor?

Comment: Yes, it works in Editor.

Comment: Are you allowed to post the url? If so, post it like it is.

Comment: I can't post the url but I can confirm that when I open that page in my PC, the view is different. And when I open that in my android phone, the page is much smaller with different view.

Comment: Does the url contain a username and password? If not then the problem is likely what [tier1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41348108/3785314) said.

Comment: No, there is no authentication required to access the page. Can you help me to implement @tier1's solution in Unity? I am not sure how to set headers in Unity.

Comment: Try checking if `www.isDone` is actually `true`, i do expect it to be true after the yield, but i have seen cases where it is not.

Comment: You can check the implementation. If that doesn't work then the problem is something I cannot help with since I don't have the url and therefore cannot test it.

Comment: @Paradox Thanks for your advice, I'll check that in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation of [tier1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348108/3785314)'s answer.

**POST Request**:

```
private IEnumerator FetchText()
{
    string URL = "www.yahoo.com";
    string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";

    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    headers.Add("User-Agent", userAgent);
    string postData = "test";
    string data = "data=" + postData;

    WWW www = new WWW(URL, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), headers);
    yield return www;


    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        //myText.text = www.text.Length.ToString();
        Debug.Log("Got: " + www.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Error: " + www.error);
    }
}
```

**GET Request**:

Setting the `WWW` `byte[] postData` parameter to null will make it a GET request.

```
private IEnumerator FetchText()
{

    string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";
    string URL = "www.yahoo.com";

    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    headers.Add("User-Agent", userAgent);

    WWW www = new WWW(URL, null, headers);
    yield return www;


    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        //myText.text = www.text.Length.ToString();
        Debug.Log("Got: " + www.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Error: " + www.error);
    }
}
```

*According your original code, you need the GET request method.* This will masquerade as request from a Chrome browser. You can get your `User-Agent` from [here](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/).

Comment: I'll try it now and will let you know.

Comment: I think you might help me with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885413/extract-byte-arrays-of-individual-frames-from-byte-array-of-a-gif-file

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the URL you are trying to fetch is detecting your user agent and sending you to some kind of mobile site with a smaller response body.

I'm not very familiar with the library you're using but you might want to try manually setting the User-Agent header.

For example:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Comment: I'll try that and will get back to you.