# Google Map Geocoding API gives different results on different platforms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am working on a project that needs to find lattitude and longitude values for given address. I create a correct link (like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?new_forward_geocoder=true&sensor=false&address=new%20york%20usa ) by input text on my application(unity3d). It works properly. However, If I copy the same link  and paste it to browser it gives me different "lat"-"long" values, different "formatted_address" values. How is this even possible? Thanks in advance.

PS: By the way I have also API Key, but I didn't write in this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is using the headers your browser sent to it to detect when you are making a request from a known Web Browser or not. It looks like they respond to Google Maps request based on this.

Most of the time, this is done by checking the "*User-Agent*" header. Other times, it is done by checking "*User-Agent*" and other headers too.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348855/3785314) is a complete solution for making GET or POST with a custom "*User-Agent*" header in Unity.

*Remember, if this does not work, you simply have to install Wireshark, then make a request to the Google Map server with the link in your question. Wireshark will give you all the headers. Now, try to send all of them until you figure out which ones are used by the server to do the checking*.