# Extract byte arrays of individual frames from byte array of a GIF file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `byte[]` of a GIF file. I want to extract all of the frames from it. I am able to extract the frames using `System.Drawing.Image` and `System.Drawing.Imaging`. But these require `System.Drawing` which I can't use in my project since Unity doesn't support that. If in some way, I could get `byte[]` of each frame, it will fulfill my needs.

Anybody has a solution or some alternatives for this problem?