# get textures from server in unity for android platform

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

How can I get textures from server in unity for android platform
www and unitywebrequest are not working on android.. they work fine inside of editor

www class gives connection refused exception 
and unityweb request gives unknown error

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class UIpopulator : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] Recentthumb;
public GameObject featuredThumb;
//public GameObject videoThumb;
jsonparse jp;
public Text uu;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}
public IEnumerator changeText(int i,RawImage img)
{
    string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";
    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    headers.Add("User-Agent", userAgent);
    jp = GetComponent<jsonparse>();
    // Start a download of the given URL
    WWW www = new WWW(jp.turl[i],null,headers);
    print("progress :"+www.progress);
    // Wait for download to complete
    yield return www;
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        uu.text = "success";
        img.texture = www.texture;

    }
    else
    {
        uu.text = www.error;
    }
    img.GetComponent<videoUrl>().setUrl(jp.vurl[i]);

}
IEnumerator GetTexture(int i, RawImage img)
{
    jp = GetComponent<jsonparse>();
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.GetTexture(jp.turl[i]);
    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.isError)
    {
        uu.text = www.error;
    }
    else {
        img.texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
    }
    img.GetComponent<videoUrl>().setUrl(jp.vurl[i]);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
void SaveTextureToFile(Texture2D texture, string filename)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, texture.EncodeToPNG());
}
void setRecentThumb()
{
    int i = jsonparse.videoCount;
    StartCoroutine(changeText(i - 1, Recentthumb[0].GetComponent<RawImage>()));
    StartCoroutine(changeText(i - 2, Recentthumb[1].GetComponent<RawImage>()));
}
void setFeatured()
{
    int i = jsonparse.videoCount;
    StartCoroutine(changeText(0, featuredThumb.GetComponent<RawImage>()));
}

public void UiSetup()
{
    setRecentThumb();
    setFeatured();
}
```

}

Comment: Build it on PC and test it. If the build works on PC then the problem is likely  "User-Agent". If this is the problem this is a duplicate and you can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41348855/3785314).

Comment: yes pc build works.. but I am trying to get the textures from local server.. and I tried the solution from that thread too.. it still does'nt work

Comment: I know you are trying to get image from the server. What exactly did you try? Can you update your question with the modified code you tried?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Ok nice. I noticed you are doing the-same thing in changeText and GetTexture functions. Which one are you actually using? I expect you to be using changeText  at this moment.

Comment: yes .. I am using changeText method

Comment: Very weird problem. What is your Unity version and what does the url you use to access the image look like?

Comment: unity version is 5.50f3 and am trying to access the textures from the url I get from a json file
This is the url of json : http://192.168.0.4/chillivr/wp-content/content/vid.json
and for one of the image this is the url : http://localhost/chillivr/wp-content/content/videos/featured/Thumb.png

Comment: ok I guess the problem is I in json .. the url of image ..

Comment: Instead of using localhost for the image url, why not use the IP of the server  like you did for the json? *192.168.0.4/chillivr/wp-content/content/videos/featured/Thumb.‌​png* While doing it make sure that you are on the-same network as the server computer.

Comment: localhost  = this computer/device. Since the server is running on another computer/device, localhost should not work unless you are running that app on the-same machine as the server. Try that solution and let me know.

Comment: :D yes .. got it.. silly mistake .. thank you

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: yes it works .. thank you