# Is there a way to determine the amount of disk space an app has used in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filesystems, storage, diskspace

I've seen many posts about how to get the amount of free space the iOS device has, or how much free space the iOS device has, but is there a way to determine how much space the app itself has used? (Including the app itself and all of its resources/documents/cache/etc). This would be the same value that can be seen in Settings->General->iPhone Storage.

Comment: Duplicated with an existing question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49812282/1982185

Comment: This is different as that question/answer does not address disk space used by only the app itself, but rather used disk space by all content on the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to do this:

I created a category on `NSFileManager` and added:

```
-(NSUInteger)applicationSize
    NSString *appgroup = @"Your App Group"; // Might not be necessary in your case.

    NSURL *appGroupURL = [self containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:appgroup];
    NSURL *documentsURL = [[self URLsForDirectory: NSDocumentDirectory inDomains: NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
    NSURL *cachesURL = [[self URLsForDirectory: NSCachesDirectory inDomains: NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];

    NSUInteger appGroupSize = [appGroupURL fileSize];
    NSUInteger documentsSize = [documentsURL fileSize];
    NSUInteger cachesSize = [cachesURL fileSize];
    NSUInteger bundleSize = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] fileSize];
    return appGroupSize + documentsSize + cachesSize + bundleSize;
}
```

I also added a category on `NSURL` with the following:

```
-(NSUInteger)fileSize
{
    BOOL isDir = NO;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:self.path isDirectory:&isDir];
    if (isDir)
        return [self directorySize];
    else
        return [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:self.path error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileSize] unsignedIntegerValue];
}

-(NSUInteger)directorySize
{
    NSUInteger result = 0;
    NSArray *properties = @[NSURLLocalizedNameKey, NSURLCreationDateKey, NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey];
    NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:self includingPropertiesForKeys:properties options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil];
    for (NSURL *url in files)
    {
        result += [url fileSize];
    }

    return result;
}
```

It takes a bit to run if you have a lot of app data, but it works.