# How to get current sandbox size or app size

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to get the total size of my app or the sandbox size. Is there any official way to get this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the amount of disk space being used by your app's sandbox?

Comment: Yes, I want to get this.

Comment: Here's a solution in Objective-C. Should be simple enough to translate to Swift. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991278/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-amount-of-disk-space-an-app-has-used-in-ios?s=2|47.7361

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to know app size without any kind of coding then there is a way. As Apple applies their own logic to give only supported assets to the device which downloads your app, app size varies between devices.

Follow below steps:

1. Archive and upload your latest build to AppStore
2. Login to https://itunesconnect.apple.com
3. Go to your app's "Activity" tab and wait until its finished "Processing"
4. Then click on your latest uploaded build number and find `App Store File Sizes` link
5. Then you are able to see estimated app size on different devices like below
   [image: Estimated app size on different devices]

And if you only want to see app size on particular device then you can see that in TestFlight App, undar `App Details` menu