# How to get free internal storage space using Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I can get RAM details using (NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.PhysicalMemory). But i want to get free internal device storage using Xamarin IOS.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried.. all the code i am getting either for SWIFT or Objective C. I am using xamarin ios (C#). So i need code related to that.

Comment: Did you try to convert the objective-c code to c#?

Comment: i am new to Objective -C and C#. I dont have much knowledge on that. How to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device

Comment: this is the code i got it from google. But it using Objective -C

Comment: Okay let me try to convert it for you

Comment: @EsrathMuqayyar Do you have any cache memory issue while implementing this ? I am having [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400844/get-ios-internal-storage-memory-information-xamarin-forms-ios#). I tried following answer code as well, but it is not helpful. Please check comments in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method for getting the internal free space is this one:

```
  NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetFileSystemAttributes (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)).FreeSize;
```

If you are using `Xamarin.Forms`, you can make a custom interface

```
namespace Your.Namespace.Interfaces
{
    public interface IStorageInterface
    {
        double GetFreeSpace(); //Not sure about the return type, try long, or double

    }
}
```

In your iOS Project:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Your.Namespace.iOS.StorageRenderer))]
namespace Your.Namespace.iOS
{
    public class StorageRenderer : IStorageInterface
    {
        public double GetFreeSpace()
        {
            return NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetFileSystemAttributes (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)).FreeSize;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have converted your code into Xamarin.iOS and it is as follows:

```
private ulong GetFreeDiskspace()
    {
        ulong totalSpace = 0;
        ulong totalFreeSpace = 0;
        NSError error = null;
        string[] paths = NSSearchPath.GetDirectories(NSSearchPathDirectory.UserDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.All);
        var defManager = NSFileManager.DefaultManager;
        var dicAttributes = defManager.
            GetFileSystemAttributes(paths.First()
            , out error);
        totalSpace = dicAttributes.Size;
        totalFreeSpace = dicAttributes.FreeSize;
        return totalFreeSpace;
    }
```

Good luck!

In case of queries revert!

Comment: Thank Hakim for the help